# Terminal command to run apps without GPU acceleration

Tags: command-line, graphics, 22.04

Some time ago I found a page with a tip about a command you can type in the terminal, after which any command or app run in that terminal window will be run without discrete graphic acceleration. I can't seem to find that command any longer. Does anyone know how this command goes?

More generally, I want to run an application but force it to not use my graphic card. Any advices?

Edit: As advised by @ChanganAuto, I'm adding my Graphic Card model here: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49]

Comment: If you have Nvidia (+ iGPU) with correct drivers installed then you don't even need a command since all can be done via the Nvidia X Server Settings tool. About command you're probably thinking about prime-select...

Comment: No, I don't have Nvidia, unfortunately. I have `Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49]`

Comment: If so adding that info to the question would be a good idea along with a more in dept explanation of your goal. I'm not aware of any command.